# jQuery - add content from one UL to another based on shared class

Tags: jquery, replace, each

Having some trouble figuring this one out in jQuery: I need to add content from LI's in an earlier UL to a later UL, *if* they share the same class. In other words, I have the following two lists in the HTML:

```
<ul id="bullet-content">
    <li class="shared-class-1">
        <h3>First Title</h3>
        <p>First Content</p>
    </li>
    <li class="shared-class-2">
        <h3>Second Title</h3>
        <p>Second Content</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then:

```
<ul class="bullets">
     <li class="shared-class-1">
         <h3 class="bullet-title">#</h3>
         <p class="bullet-content">#</p>
     </li>
     <li class="shared-class-2">
         <h3 class="bullet-title">#</h3>
         <p class="bullet-content">#</p>
     </li>
</ul>
```

To transfer the content from "bullet-content" to "bullets" I have the following jQuery (it also adds or removes an 'active' class depending on whether the li's share class names):

```
$('.bullets li').each( function(j) { 
    var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/); 
    for (var j=0,len=classes.length; j<len; j++){             
        var bulletDisplay = $('#bullet-content li');
        var bulletContentTitle = $(bulletDisplay).find('h3').html();
        var bulletContentBody = $(bulletDisplay).find('p').html();                    
        if ($(bulletDisplay).hasClass(classes[j])){ 
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).find('h3').html(bulletContentTitle);
            $(this).find('p').html(bulletContentBody);
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    }   
});
```

This sort of works, but both of the '.bullets li' end up getting populated with the same content -- from the first li of 'bullet-content' instead of from both of those lis. I guess another loop makes sense, but I'm trying to figure out how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to populate first `.bullets li` with first `.bullet-content li` and second with second?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use index of your current `.bullet-content li` element to select corresponding `.bullets li`. For this only two small changes needed - in the first line of the script (note that here `j` is substituted by `i` - we will use it later, but it is not a good idea to use the same variables for indices anyway):

```
$('.bullets li').each( function(i) {
```

and in the forth one:

```
var bulletDisplay = $('#bullet-content li:eq(' + i + ')');
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ShfN/) with the result.

Answer (score 0):

may have missed something, based on what i am seeing, this should prob cover the bases

```
    $(function ()
    {
        $('li', $('#bullet-content')).appendTo('.bullets');

        $('.bullets li').each(function ()
        {
            $($(this).attr('class').split(' ')).each
            (function ()
            {
                if($('.' + this).length > 1)
                {
                    $('.' + this).addClass('active');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.' + this).removeClass('active');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: may have misunderstood, are you only moving when the class are the same or always moving and adding class when they are the same?